Get time taken for each process during startup
I'm able to list processes that are loaded during boot time using Get-EventLog.
But I'm trying to get time taken to load for each process.
$bootTime = (Get-CimInstance win32_Operatingsystem).lastbootuptime

"Boot time is $($bootTime)"

Foreach($log in Get-Eventlog -list)
{
    "Events from $($log.Log) event log"
    Get-EventLog -LogName $log.Log -After $bootTime -Before $bootTime.AddMinutes(5) -ea 0
}

Results:
PS C:\Users\rw\Documents\temp> .\GetBootupLogEntries.ps1
Boot time is 04/23/2024 11:22:40
Events from Application event log
Events from Cisco AnyConnect ISE Posture Module event log
Events from Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client event log
Events from HardwareEvents event log
Events from IntelAudioServiceLog event log
Events from Internet Explorer event log
Events from Key Management Service event log
Events from OAlerts event log
Events from Security event log
Events from System event log

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
   33146 Apr 23 11:26  Information Microsoft-Windows...         1502 The Group Policy settings for the computer were...
   33145 Apr 23 11:26  Information Microsoft-Windows...         1502 The Group Policy settings for the computer were...
   33144 Apr 23 11:26  Information Microsoft-Windows...         1502 The Group Policy settings for the computer were...
   33143 Apr 23 11:26  Information Microsoft-Windows...         1502 The Group Policy settings for the computer were...
   33142 Apr 23 11:26  Warning     Microsoft-Windows...         1014 Name resolution for the name www.bing.com timed...
   33141 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          114 Removed URL (http://*:2869/upnp/eventing/) from...
   33140 Apr 23 11:25  Warning     DCOM                        10016 The description for Event ID '10016' in Source ...
   33139 Apr 23 11:25  Warning     DCOM                        10016 The description for Event ID '10016' in Source ...
   33138 Apr 23 11:25  Warning     DCOM                        10016 The description for Event ID '10016' in Source ...
   33137 Apr 23 11:25  Warning     DCOM                        10016 The description for Event ID '10016' in Source ...
   33136 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          102 Networking driver in E5B63289-BB86-48C2-B87B-40...
   33135 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          232 NIC E5B63289-BB86-48C2-B87B-40B8DC7C28E5--3A904...
   33134 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          233 The operation '7' succeeded on nic E5B63289-BB8...
   33133 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          232 NIC 790E58B4-7939-4434-9358-89AE7DDBE87F (Frien...
   33132 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...            7 Miniport NIC 790E58B4-7939-4434-9358-89AE7DDBE8...
   33131 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          233 The operation '7' succeeded on nic 790E58B4-793...
   33130 Apr 23 11:25  Information Microsoft-Windows...          264 Port 790E58B4-7939-4434-9358-89AE7DDBE87F (Frie...
   33129 Apr 23 11:25  Information VfpExt                 1073748860 The  service entered the Filter restart complet...
   33128 Apr 23 11:25  Information VfpExt                 1073748860 The  service entered the Filter restart start s...

This is a screenshot from Windows Diagnostics Event log, and it shows total time taken for the selected process.

Please help me get the boot/load time taken using powershell cmdlet. Thanks.

Refine the following for your purposes (run elevated): Get-WinEvent -Path "$env:SystemRoot\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance%4Operational.evtx" -MaxEvents 10 | ForEach-Object {$_.Id, $_.LevelDisplayName -join ': '; ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object Name -match "Time|IsDegradation|^Name$"} ?
